# Using -moz-transform on a div element

Tags: css

I'm trying to make the `<div id = "sun">` tag containing the png image of sun rotate 360 degrees, so the appearance is that the sun is animated and moving around and around. It seems that the rotate property alone my not be sufficient. Here is the webpage I am applying it to:

http://www.manchestergardeningservices.co.uk/

and here is the webpage that has the effect working I am trying to achieve:

http://outsideapp.com/

Here is the [transform CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/transform?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS/-moz-transform) I have applied in my styling for the element.  May I ask if I have applied the property in the wrong way? And my second question - is there a webkit version of this CSS property?

```
#sun {  
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    float: left;
    height: 350px;
    margin-left: -100px;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-top: -185px;
    width: 350px;
    z-index: 100;  
    display: inline;       
}
```

Comment: What makes you think you applied it wrong?  That is a very vague question.

Comment: I haven't seemingly done anything wrong, naming my div correctly and applying the transform property in my CSS rule. I was just hoping an extra pair of eyes may see an error I have made.

Comment: You pulled the CSS and markup from the site, but forgot the [JavaScript](http://outsideapp.com/javascript/sidewayscoding2.js).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking to animate it, rather than simply transform it. A transform won't be an animation, it'll just show the final result.

Here's an overview of keyframe animation using CSS: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/webkit-keyframe-animation-syntax/

Here's a quickly mocked up version to illustrate how the animation can be applied to a div: http://jsfiddle.net/donovanh/rhEnY/

### Note: prefixes

^ The above includes prefixes for the major browsers as well as the unprefixed version for when the prefixes are dropped. It's important to not rely on a specific prefix (such as -moz) as they are only meant as temporary measures until the CSS is properly supported and the prefix is dropped.

In case JSFiddle deletes the example, here's the CSS:

```
#sun {
    background-color: yellow;
    border: 5px solid black;
    border-radius: 20px;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    margin:20px;
     -webkit-animation: rotateAnimation 5s infinite linear;
     -moz-animation:    rotateAnimation 5s infinite linear;
     -ms-animation:     rotateAnimation 5s infinite linear;
     -o-animation:      rotateAnimation 5s infinite linear;
     animation:         rotateAnimation 5s infinite linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotateAnimation {
    0%   { -webkit-transform:rotate(0);}
    100%   { -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);}
}
@-moz-keyframes rotateAnimation {
    0%   { -moz-transform:rotate(0);}
    100%   { -moz-transform:rotate(360deg);}
}
@-ms-keyframes rotateAnimation {
    0%   { -ms-transform:rotate(0);}
    100%   { -ms-transform:rotate(360deg);}
}
@-o-keyframes rotateAnimation {
    0%   { -o-transform:rotate(0);}
    100%   { -o-transform:rotate(360deg);}
}
@keyframes rotateAnimation {
    0%   { transform:rotate(0);}
    100%   { transform:rotate(360deg);}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rotating an object by 360 degrees results in the same object. That's why you don't see any change. You could try other degrees, e.g. `180deg`. Only if you would apply a css `transition` on the transform property, you might see an effect with `rotate(360deg)`.

There is a webkit version of this property, simply `-webkit-transform`. You should also add the property without any vendor prefixes, because the support for the prefixed versions will maybe dropped some day.

**Edit:** To rotate continuously:

```
@-moz-keyframes rotate {
 from {
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
 }
 to {
  -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
 }
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
 from {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
 }
 to {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
 }
}
@keyframes rotate {
 from {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
 }
 to {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
 }
}
#sun {
 -moz-animation: rotate 5s linear infinite;
 -webkit-animation: rotate 5s linear infinite;
 animation: rotate 5s linear infinite;
}
```

Comment: Have you added the `@keyframes`? Does this test page work: http://result.dabblet.com/gist/3386977/74bd7c6b40d735cf88b47be52021e776e2be6034

Comment: yes the test page does work, thankyou. I shall use it as a frame of reference.

Comment: Sorry, I've forgotten the `-moz-` before `keyframes`. Now it should work.